# How does selenium behave without an "active session"

Tags: selenium

I've been working with Selenium for a few years already.

I started with some little stuff in Java and in my previous job I did a project using C# bindings with SpecFlow framework, page objects model, I dealt with complex locators, some JavascriptExecutor even some browsermobproxy work, bottom line I have some experience with Selenium.

Still there is something that is not clear to me.

Is Selenium expected to work properly when there is no "interactive session" into the machine that is running the code ?

Let's say that I connect into remote desktop to a machine in the cloud (Let's say Amazon or Azure), I develop a script and schedule a windows job to run it on the next 10 minutes, then I disconnect from the remote desktop session, the machine is on but no user is connected to it in remote desktop.

Will the script work ? Or depends what does it do ? Might some of the actions not work (Script might include changing the window size, sending keystrokes both through selenium sendkeys and by OS level actions) ? Can we ensure that any script that we developed and works OK while we are connected to the machine will also work when I'm not ?

I hope the question is clear, if not I can maybe explain further

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Selenium can run on the cloud machine even though you are not connected to it. It should work without any issue. 
As per my knowledge cloud machines are protected by firewall which blocks almost all the ports. You may need to get permission to use the default selenium ports like 4444 or 5555.
Also, may need to increase wait time because the cloud machines are slow in performance compared to normal physical desktop.

Usually cloud machines are linux based, you need to consider the environment as well.

Comment: My question is not about running on the cloud, is in general about running Selenium when there is no active session to the machine that is running. I've had issues before with this (For example sending sendkeys of C# to a windows dialog doesn't work with no active session) so the question is in general if selenium is prepared to run with no interactive session for any scenario...

Comment: Yes, You can run without any active session. but I am not sure about the window dialog issue will work or not.